# Authorization for different users on active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

If I have many models for different users to manage them.

User A is responsible for CAR, ORDER, SHIP

User B is responsible for PLANE, ORDER

Every user should only modify the models they are resposible for.

How to do it on active_admin ?

Any articles to refer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CanCan is an authorization library for Ruby on Rails which restricts what resources a given user is allowed to access. All permissions are defined in a single location (the Ability class) and not duplicated across controllers, views, and database queries.

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

And you also need some role manager: https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify

So you can write in the ability.rb:

```
if current_admin_user.has_role? :roleA
  can :manage Car, Order, Ship
elsif current_admin_user.has_role? :roleB
  can :manage, Plane, Order
end
```